# Merge two arrays and compare by ID add new Property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hopefully someone can help me out here.

I am building an angular app with SQLite database which stores existing values. I need to compare these values from a json array received over http.

They should be matched by code, I want to compare the existing values with the update values add the property "active" = 1 otherwise active = 0 .

I tried a double foreach loop below, but I guess what's happening is the index is off so the results are not accurate in my actual application.

I have lodash available if there is some way to do this using that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

How can I get the following output

```
/*epected output 
[{
    "name": "Person 1"
    "code": '001',
    "active": '1'
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2"
    "code": '002',
    "active": '1'
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 3"
    "code": '003',
    "active": '0' // note active 0 since doesnt exist in exsting 
  }
]*/
```

and what I tried along with 500 other things.

```js
const existing = [{
    "name": "Person 1",
    "code": '001',
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2",
    "code": '002',
  },
];

const update = [{
    "name": "Person 1",
    "code": '001',
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2",
    "code": '002',
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 3",
    "code": '003',
  },
];

existing.forEach(element => {
  update.forEach(test => {
    if (element.code === test.code) {
      element.avtive = true;
    } else {
      element.avtive = false;
    }
  });
  return element;
});


console.log(existing);


/*epected output 
[{
    "name": "Person 1"
    "code": '001',
    "active": '1'
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2"
    "code": '002',
    "active": '1'
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 3"
    "code": '003',
    "active": '0' // note active 0 since doesnt exist in exsting 
  }
]*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @radovix answer above, which worked for me, I came up with something slightly more long-winded, but which gives the same end result, but also separate lists of active and inactive:

```
  let active = update.filter(item =>{
    return existing.find(exist=> exist.code == item.code);
  });

  let inactive = update.filter(item =>{
    return !existing.find(exist=> exist.code == item.code);
  });

  active = active.map(item=>({...item, active: '1'}));
  inactive= inactive.map(item=>({...item, active: '0'}));

  const merged = [...this.active, ...this.inactive];
```

You can see both ways working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-merge-arrays-update-property

Comment: This one ia good. Much appreciated.  Awarding since you provided full demo as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what should work for you. All existing code are extracted and then, for each updated value it is checked whether code exists in `existingCodes` array.

```
const existingCodes = existing.map((e) => e.code);

const result = updated.map((e) => ({ 
  ...e, 
  active: existingCodes.includes(e.code) ? '1' : '0'
});
```

If `includes` doesn't work for you on IE, you can replace this line `existingCodes.includes(e.code)` with `existingCodes.filter((code) => code === e.code).length`.

Comment: Thanks. This one not. working for me. Whats happens is I lose my originally (existing) values.  I am basically trying to get a merged array so I can disable a button on instances that have already been installed.   So if a value in update doesn't exist the button will be enabled, if it does exists its disabled  (based on active)

Comment: Hey, not sure I understand you totally. What you trying to say is that your final array needs object from both arrays (those that only existed in one of them before)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`, `find` and remove item from update array as

```
let result= existing.reduce((acc, item)=>{
let found = update.find(c => c.name == item.name);
      if (found != undefined) {

        const index = update.indexOf(found);

        if (index > -1) {
          update.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      item.active = true;
      acc.push(item);
      return acc;
},[]);

update.map(c=> c.active = false);

//console.log(update)
result = result.concat(update);
console.log(result);
```

```js
const existing = [{
    "name": "Person 1",
    "code": '001',
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2",
    "code": '002',
  },
];

const update = [{
    "name": "Person 1",
    "code": '001',
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 2",
    "code": '002',
  },
  {
    "name": "Person 3",
    "code": '003',
  },
];

let result= existing.reduce((acc, item)=>{
let found = update.find(c => c.name == item.name);
      if (found != undefined) {
        
        const index = update.indexOf(found);
        
        if (index > -1) {
          update.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      item.active = true;
      acc.push(item);
      return acc;
},[]);

update.map(c=> c.active = false);

//console.log(update)
result = result.concat(update);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice.  This works, but anyway to simplify it a bit? I have lodash as well.